# How can I create my own apple mdm server to control children devices

Tags: ios, mdm, parental-control

I'm developing a parental control application for iOS. I want to block some applications on children's devices by order of their parents. after a lot of searches, I realized that we must use something called an MDM server. but I don't know how can I set up an MDM server and should I use third party services? Does Apple have any solution for this? I mean something that can be implemented easily. we will have a lot of users for this project and we must choose a stable and reliable solution.

I already have an Apple Enterprise Developer program membership.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Creating an MDM service is a significant piece of work. You will need to obtain an Apple Enterprise Developer program membership in addition to the organisational membership to start. Apple does not recommend using MDM services for parental controls. The [Managed Settings](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ManagedSettings?changes=latest_minor) framework is recommended.

Comment: I already have Apple Enterprise Developer Program. But I dont know how can I start

Comment: As I said, this is an enormous undertaking. First you will need to create server side code that is capable of generating signed management profiles using a key from your enterprise program and deliver these to target devices via a web interface. You will also need server side code that can send MDM commands to your managed devices. You will need a "parent" app that can authenticate to your server and set up the policies for the children and a "child" app that is used to register with your server and request the management profiles.

Comment: As well as the MDM/policy system you need an account registration, management and authentication system. Apple's documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement). However, as I said above, MDM is the wrong approach for a parental control app,   The managed settings framework is much easier to work with and is specifically designed for parental controls.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for the answer. Can I restrict some applications with managed settings framework? we want to restrict some applications on child devices remotely. because we have two applications, one for the parents and another for the child.

Comment: That is exactly what it does. Read the documents I linked to in my first comment and watch the WWDC videos on managed settings

Answer (score 0):

You can use Macbook or Mac mini, install Apple Configurator App from Mac store and use this App to create restriction profile.
Then install profile to iPhones.
In profile you can prohibit any apps to install and so on…
I don’t remember now, but some profile settings can be used only for supervised devices. To supervise device you can use Configurator 2. Device will be restored during supervising!!!

Comment: You can protect your profile to delete by password.